# Instrument validation: Proportional-odds ordinal regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, ordered-logit, validity

I am looking for advice on the best statistical tests to use to accomplish my goal. I am making a new instrument to measure a variable and want to compare it to the current (gold standard) instrument. The current instrument's outcomes are ordinal (i.e., High, Medium, Low). The new instrument outcomes would be continuous (i.e., 1-100). The participant already has an existing score on the old instrument. They will be scored on the new instrument as part of this study. So it will be two scores for each participant.

In order to test if the new instrument scores align with the old instrument outcomes, I believe I'd be using a proportional-odds ordinal regression and I would say: I am predicting an ordinal dependent variable (Rate) given continuous independent variable (Score). My results would be reported something like "An increase in NewMeasure score was associated with an increase in the odds of the OldMesureRank being High". Is this the best test to perform here? Is this the correct way to use/interpret the proportional-odds ordinal regression?

Additionally, the NewMeasure has subscales, and I'd like to explore if any of the subscales differ in their contribution to the overall score (i.e., the first subscale weights more heavily in higher scores than the rest, while the third subscale weights more heavily in lower scores than the rest). My results would be reported something like "Higher scores on Subscale 1 contributes more to an overall higher score than the other subscales. Lower scores on Subscale 3 contributes more to an overall lower score than the other subscales." Would this still be a proportional-odds ordinal regression or would it be better as a stepwise discriminate analysis or a weighted linear regression (or something else)?

[*as a note, I will be doing other validation explorations of the new instrument, this question relates specifically to how to compare it to the existing gold standard appropriately]

Comment: What's the design? Did you implement the new and old instruments in the same people or different people? If different, are the scale(s) determined to be measurement invariant, or do you need to adjust for covariates? A proportional odds model is just one modeling technique to determine a way to score such an instrument.

Comment: The participant already has an existing score on the old instrument. They will be scored on the new instrument as part of this study. So it will be two scores for each participant.

Comment: You say *participant*. Does N=1? You can't do anything with N=1. If the new instrument has subscales, there are some reasons why, for instance, calibration is not needed: you are asserting the new instrument is more precise, so they won't be perfectly predictive of each other. So it might make sense to explore some item response theory tools (like 2PL) for the old scale and the new one. Hopefully you can show better consistency in the new tool, whether a sumscore is a valid technique for *either* tool in the new sample, and - something not often done - cross validation.

Comment: Right now I am aiming for N = 100. Thousands of people already have a score on the original measure so I just need to select some from that pool for taking the new measure.